# android put loading message when load another acitvity

Tags: java, android

Actually my question is very simple and I'm new in android,

How to put loading message (whether text or progress bar) after user click on new activity,

I have 2 activity both are: **MainActivity** and **DashboardActivity**

Here's **MainActivity** code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   findViewById(R.id.textViewTest).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class));
        }
    });
  }
}
```

About **DashboardActivity** :

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Toolbar mTopToolbar;
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private int progressStatus = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

        // Find the toolbar view inside the activity layout
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        // Sets the Toolbar to act as the ActionBar for this Activity window.
        // Make sure the toolbar exists in the activity and is not null
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        View hview = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
/* end class */
}
```

Please see these images :

**MainActivity**

[image]

When I open **dashboard** activity (by clicking **Test only**) it's show blank page approximately 4 - 5 seconds like this :

[image]

before content loaded completely.

**Q** : My expectation is how to display loading text or progressbar when Dashboard activity blank  / still loading?

please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can show progressbar when text  or any data is loading. Once the data is ready just hide the progress bar and show textview. Here's an example

In your DashboardActivity layout, add below preogress bar as a direct child and is visible by default.

```
   <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="#000000"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="multiply" />
```

Now hide all your textviews by adding attribute

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

In your DashboardActivity class, first when it opens progress bar starts loading. When your data is ready and set it to text. Now hide your progress bar and show TextView.

```
resultTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
yourProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

That's it.

Comment: Things that make my android slow because I used asynctask and cause frameskipping

Comment: Okay. Hide textview and show progressbar when data is loading. When data is ready just hide the progressbar and show textview.

Comment: Hello , Thank you for reply, I'll try it.